# How do I check for URLs that can be opened in an Android app?

Tags: android

URL example: `vine://post/1078432092175687680`

Right now, my app contains a webview, and it manages arbitrary URLs as the user surfs the web. Sometimes. it opens URLs that are really intent URLs.

Like the vine app for example.

So 2 parts to this question:

(a) How can I check if the above URL can be opened by an app installed in the phone?

(b) How can I convert the URL to an intent to be opened?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I convert the URL to an intent to be opened?

```
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(yourUrlGoesHere));
```

> How can I check if the above URL can be opened by an app installed in the phone?

Use `PackageManager` and `resolveActivity()` or `queryIntentActivities()`. Note that this will return things like Web browsers for `http` and `https` schemes, so if you plan on handling some URLs within your app, you will need to check for those too (e.g., via a regular expression).